# Inserção de dados no sql após validação

Tags: mysql

Preciso realizar uma validação onde eu somente possa inserir o cadastro de uma corrida no banco de dados caso o `id` do motorista e do usuário estejam presentes nos seus respectivos bancos.

Qual o melhor algoritmo para lidar com essa situação?

Segue as tabelas do banco:

```
CREATE TABLE `corridas` (
  `id_corrida` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `m_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_valor` int(9) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_corrida`),
  KEY `fk_motorista` (`m_id`),
  KEY `fk_passageiros` (`p_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `motorista` (
  `m_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `m_nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `m_nasc` datetime NOT NULL,
  `m_cpf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `m_modeloCarro` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_sexo` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `m_status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `passageiro` (
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p_nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_nasc` datetime NOT NULL,
  `p_cpf` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `p_sexo` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`)
);
```

Comment: Tás trabalhando com PHP? Não seriam os ids nas suas respectivas tabelas?

Comment: estou usando php mas como estou estudando nunca fiz algo parecido

Comment: Edita a tua pergunta e coloca as tabelas do banco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do lado do banco o que mantém a consistência das relações são *constraints* do tipo *Foreign Key* ([chave estrangeira](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chave_estrangeira)):

```
ALTER TABLE corridas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_motorista FOREIGN KEY (m_id) REFERENCES motorista(m_id);
ALTER TABLE corridas ADD CONSTRAINT fk_passageiro FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES passageiro(p_id);
```

As `KEYS` que você adicionou na sua tabela são apenas índices.

*Foreign Keys* não funcionam em tabelas que usam a *storage engine* [MyISAM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html), sendo recomendado o uso de [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html).

Para saber que tipo de *engine* suas tabelas estão usando use a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       ENGINE
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('corridas', 'motorista', 'passageiro');
```

Se for necessário alterar a *engine*:

```
ALTER TABLE passageiro ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE motorista ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE corridas ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Se você estiver usando InnoDB as duas `KEYS` originais são desnecessárias uma vez que o MySQL indexa *Foreign Keys* automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tu não vai precisar fazer esse tipo de validação, já que tu vai listar os motoristas e usuários e então selecioná-los, correto?

Quando tu for trazer esses dados para o formulário, é só trazer os nomes e os *ids* de ambos. Por exemplo tu pode listar cada um deles em seu respectivo *select*.

```
<select name="id_motorista">
    <option value="1">Motorista 1</option>
    <option value="2">Motorista 2</option>
</select>

<select name="id_usuario">
        <option value="1">Usuario 1</option>
        <option value="2">Usuario 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Somente a alteração na camada de *view* não é suficiente para garantir a integridade dos dados. Um usuário malicioso pode facilmente forjar um *request* com outros *ids* ou até mesmo modificar o  formulário em questão usando ferramentas como *Chrome DevTools* ou *Firebug*. É importante verificar entradas nas demais camadas.